# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64, linker issues on Yosemite with OpenCV

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, linker, osx-yosemite

I'm having a linker error trying to build some code that takes advantage of some opencv libraries.
The error itself is:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> "cv::Exception::Exception(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, int)"
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

What are common causes of this error?
My searching has turned up that a lot of people had issues compiling opencv with wrong libraries or in i386 instead of x86_64. I am fairly certain I don't have either of these issues. I installed opencv through homebrew with the flag --c++11 (build with c++11) and I got

> /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.11_1/lib/libopencv_core.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64

when I ran:

> file /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.11_1/lib/libopencv_core.dylib

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Please let me know if there is anything else I can provide that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual cause of this is that the dynamic library you are trying to link against is not installed or not symlinked into a directory searched by the linker.

This could be caused by two issues.

First, you may be giving an incomplete command to the linker when you try to build the executable.  Or second, you may have gotten a bad install from homebrew.

Lucky for you this is pretty easily managed by `pkg-config` which you can see is required if you type

`brew info opencv`

This yields 

`...
==> Dependencies
Build: cmake ✘, pkg-config ✔
Required: jpeg ✔, libpng ✘, libtiff ✔
...`

By noticing that opencv bottle from Homebrew uses pkg-config in its dependencies you can use this tool to get the linker flags for you.

An example of command line build might be

`clang++ -std=c++11 -o opencv_app opencv_test.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv)`

read the page `man pkg-config` and look for in the **DESCRIPTION** section to see where .pc files are stored.  Then browse to those files and test the `pkg-config` command to get the include and linker paths.  Once you have this working go back and try to build with these flags inserted by the $(pkg-config ...) expansion.

**EDIT** After writing this post I went ahead and installed opencv via Homebrew in order to check that the `pkg-config` advice would work.  The default `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` does not include the directory where Homebrew stores the *.pc files so you need to do one more thing.  Type 
`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`.  Then you should be
able to run `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` with no problem like I was.

Comment: Unfortunately, it turned out to be some issues with libc++ and libstdc++ and I ended up just using an Ubuntu VM instead. Thanks for your help!